# How to restart a serverSocket in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I am trying to add a restart server function that ejects all players and threads, then starts a new server socket for new players. This is how I have tried it, but when I restart, then try to add more players they don't connect?

Any help would be awesome, thanks. Alternatively, is there a way to eject all connections from server without closing socket?

```
private volatile ServerSocket ss;

private Socket p1;
private Socket p2;

private GameSession ses;

private ObjectOutputStream top1;
private ObjectOutputStream top2;

 public void connectToClient() {
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(8000);

        while (true) {


            p1 = ss.accept();

            top1 = new ObjectOutputStream(p1.getOutputStream());

            p2 = ss.accept();

            top2 = new ObjectOutputStream(p2.getOutputStream());

            see = new GameSession(p1, p2, top1, top2);

            new Thread(see).start();

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}

private void restartServer() {
    if (ss.isBound()) {
        try {
            ss.close();
            ss = new ServerSocket(8000);

            displayLog.append(new Date() + ": Server started at socket "
                    + ss.getLocalPort() + '\n');

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing on the player end? I would consider sending a message saying that you're shutting down and restarting so the players can do something useful such as trying to connect again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the ServerSocket and creating a new one doesn't accomplish anything useful. The only effect of that would be to cause connection losses on pending, un-accepted connections. Remove that.

You have to close the *accepted* sockets, and have the clients react to that by attempting to reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Your `restartServer` method does not contain any functionality to start a new game. All it does is create a new `ServerSocket` that doesn't do anything. Instead of instantiating a new `ServerSocket`, call `connectToClient`after `close`.

```
private void restartServer() {
    if (ss.isBound()) {
        try {
            ss.close();
            connectToClient();

            displayLog.append(new Date() + ": Server started at socket "
                + ss.getLocalPort() + '\n');

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, it just causes the server to hang? The connect to client is in a while loop, do i need to break that?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting a `ServerSocket` should work. I assume you are calling `restartServer` in a different Thread than `connectToClient`?
Also `ServerSocker` should be `volatile`.

Comment: I've changed it to volatile, it is using the same thread as ConnectToClient, I only introduce new threads during new game sessions. Still is not connecting new clients

Comment: Your loop is stopped by an IOException when you close the server socket. You have to restart it. Also why do you want to close the ss anyway?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the thread (First hold the instance of thread) - On closure of the thread, close the client sockets first.
2. Close the ServerSocket
3. call connectToCLient

Comment: I've passéd the instances of threads and sockets, should I hold on to them?

Comment: Hold the thread reference - You just Google how to stop the thread. Before stopping the thread close the client socket(s).